# c# и cmd команды

Tags: c#, cmd, adb, protocol

Пишу звонилку через кастомный протокол, дошел до момента, когда необходимо реализовать вызов adb команды в cmd для отправки запроса на android через usb. Переменную среду для adb в path я указал. Вот код:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
  String number = "";
  foreach (string s in args)
  {
    number = ProcessInput(s).Replace("amocall:","");
    number = "adb shell service call phone 2 s16 \"\" s16 \"" + number + "\"";
    Console.WriteLine(number);
  }

  Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C " + number);

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Проблема в том, что cmd вызывается на долю секунды и исчезает, не отработав вызов на устройство, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Например, в том, что команда не распознана. Откуда ж нам знать, какая у вас ошибка? Для отладки, поместите вашу команду в bat-файл, добавьте в нём же строку `pause` в конце, и запускайте этот bat-файл вместо вашей команды. Когда отладите, верните назад как было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему.

Как оказалось, сам вызов cmd работал прекрасно и при запуске экзешника все выполнялось так как и требовалось.

Проблемы начинались, при нажатии на номер телефона в браузере, когда шло обращение к протоколу, который был создан. И если exe файл стартовал, то для cmd запроса не хватало прав.

Решение оказалось наипростейшим. Вместо того, что бы вызывать adb через cmd, обратился к нему напрямую.

Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    String number = "";
    foreach (string s in args)
    {
        number = ProcessInput(s).Replace("amocall:","");
        i++;
    }       

    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.FileName = "adb.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "shell service call phone 2 s16 \"\" s16 \"" + number +"\"";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```